# How to use Apache Commons DirectoryWalker?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am trying to figure out how to use Apache Commons IO [`DirectoryWalker`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/DirectoryWalker.html). It's pretty easy to understand how to subclass `DirectoryWalker`.

But how do you start executing it on a particular directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the subclass should provide a public method that calls walk().

Comment: don't you hate it when that happens >.<

Comment: actually it looks like you don't have to provide a method that calls walk. another class can call walk() from the outside.

Comment: d'oh! I stand corrected, walk() is protected. you are 100% right!

Answer (score 11):

Just to expand on this answer since I was puzzled at first of how to use the class as well and this question came up on google when I was looking around. This is just an example of how I used it (minus some things):

```
public class FindConfigFilesDirectoryWalker extends DirectoryWalker {
    private static String rootFolder = "/xml_files";
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    private static IOFileFilter filter = FileFilterUtils.andFileFilter(FileFilterUtils.fileFileFilter(),
            FileFilterUtils.suffixFileFilter("xml"));

    public FeedFileDirectoryWalker() {
        super(filter, -1);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void handleFile(final File file, final int depth, final Collection results) throws IOException {
        log.debug("Found file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        results.add(file);
    }

    public List<File> getFiles() {
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

        URL url = getClass().getResource(rootFolder);

        if (url == null) {
            log.warn("Unable to find root folder of configuration files!");
            return files;
        }

        File directory = new File(url.getFile());

        try {
            walk(directory, files);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Problem finding configuration files!", e);
        }

        return files;
    }
}
```

And then you would just invoke it via the public method you created, passing in any arguments that you may want:

```
List<File> files = new FindConfigFilesDirectoryWalker().getFiles();
```

Comment: Note that getResource() requires the resource folder to be in the build path. It is further described here: http://lj4newbies.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-classgetresource-load-resource.html

Answer (score 1):

All I wanted was a collection of directories to iterate.  This subclass provided what I needed:

```
public class UDirWalker extends DirectoryWalker {
    public UDirWalker() {
        super();
    }

    public ArrayList<File> getDirectories(File startDirectory) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<File> dirs = new ArrayList<File>();
        walk(startDirectory, dirs);
        return dirs;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean handleDirectory(File directory, int depth,
        Collection results) {
        results.add(directory);
        return true;
    }
}
```